# Casting from const int to int in c++

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, codeblocks

Can we cast a `const int` into an `int` in C++ without declaring a new variable? 
This option is available in VS but how can it be used in other compilers such as Xcode, code blocks, etc?

```
const int a = 5 ;
int (a) ++ ;
```

Comment: Modifying a `const` *by any means* evokes Undefined Behavior.  Just don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is `const`. You can't legally remove the constness to mutate the variable in *any* compiler. What you're seeing in VS is that it's letting you create an unnamed temporary and incrementing THAT.

Comment: @John Dibling I ninja-edited my answer to add the words `to mutate the variable` probably while you were writing this comment.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You can change the value of a const variable but you can't guarantee your code will behave as though you did.

There is, of course, a way to do it, but first lets make sure you understand what you're asking to do:

```
const int a = 5;
```

This tells the compiler that there is a value, 5, which you want to refer to as "a", for example so you can do:

```
const int MaxNameLen = 5;
char name[MaxNameLen + 1];
```

or

```
const float pi = 3.14;
return pi * radius;
```

Compiled without optimization, this will probably produce code which injects a variable like any other and uses it as you would expect.

But by calling the variable "const" you've signed a contract with the compiler: Behave as tho this value does not change. So you can do, for example:

```
int a = 5;
*(static_cast<int*>(&a))++;
```

But as far as the compiler is concerned, a did not change. It is free to carry on behaving as tho it didn't. So if it loaded it into a register, if it sized something based on it, it is free to just go ahead and assume it can use the value "5" wherever it sees "a". For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    const int a = 5;
    (*const_cast<int*>(&a))++;
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
}
```

might print 5 or it might print 6, depends on which compiler, which settings and the context of the code. Variable "a" has an address but you told the compiler it wouldn't change, so it may already have pushed it onto the stack or loaded it into a register.

Where this is going to hurt you worst is in highly optimized because the compiler is going to produce instructions and ordering based on your promise that "a" does not change.

Comment: *note*: `const_cast` handles references as well, I'd recommend `const_cast<int&> (a)++`.